# Insert data into database with one integer value

Tags: c#, sql

I'm tyring to insert data into a table inside my database but one value needs to be an integer. How to fix this? This is is my code so far: I have 3 textboxes where the values can be put into and a button to send it.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Maak inert query
    string sqlIns = @"INSERT INTO Pizza (Soort, beschrijving, prijs)
            VALUES ('" + textBoxSoort.Text.Trim() + "','" + textBoxBescrhijving.Text.Trim() + "', '" + tetBoxPrijs +"') ";

    //Maak commando object
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sqlIns, Connectie);

    try
    {
        //Open de connectie
        Connectie.Open();

        //Voer commando uit
        command.ExecuteReader();
        Connectie.Close();

        //Opnieuw vullen DatagridVieuw
        vullendgv();
    }
    catch (OleDbException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace, "Exception details");
    }
    finally
    {
        //Sluiten van de connectie
        Connectie.Close();
        textBoxSoort.Clear();
        textBoxBescrhijving.Clear();
        tetBoxPrijs.Clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: You get any exception or error message? And you should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: You should really use parameters or you leave yourself open to sql injection.

Comment: Which one is the integer ?

Comment: You should use parameters to prevent sql injection.

Comment: @Alex My money is on `tetBoxPrijs` :)

Comment: The intiger is textBoxPrijs

Answer (score 2):

You have several issues regarding your code:

- Use parameterized queries to prevent SQL injection. [**Inline queries are the devil**](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/)!
- Validate input before placing it in a query. If the value of a TextBox should be numeric, validate this or make the TextBox accept only numeric input. To achieve this create a method that checks if the input is numeric (Regex or custom code) and if you want a numeric-only TetxBox read [**this article**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229644%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

  An example when using a regular expression to check if the input it numeric:

  ```
  string numericPattern = "^[0-9]+$";

  string input = "1zd23";
  bool result1 = Regex.IsMatch(value, numericPattern); //false

  string input = "456";
  bool result2 = Regex.IsMatch(value, numericPattern); //true
  ```

  And in a method:

  ```
  public bool IsNumeric(string input)
  {
      return Regex.IsMatch(input, "^[0-9]+$");
  }

  //Usage:
  bool result = IsNumeric("qsd4156"); //false
  ```
- In your query you're adding the TextBox-object `tetBoxPrijs` to the query, not its value. Also leave out the single quotes, otherwise this will not be treated as a numeric value in SQL. Use this code instead

  ```
  tetBoxPrijs.Text
  ```

  But this must be numeric so this should actually be:

  ```
  Convert.ToInt32(tetBoxPrijs.Text)
  ```

  Of course this is without validation of the input. Validation can be done with the provided method using the regular expression:

  ```
  if(IsNumeric(tetBoxPrijs.Text))
  {
      int prijs = Convert.ToInt32(tetBoxPrijs.Text);
      //use 'prijs' in query
  }
  ```

**Update:**

Even more simple is to use the [**Int32.TryParse method**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) as commented by GarethD:

```
int numericValue;
if(Int32.TryParse(tetBoxPrijs.Text, out numericValue))
{
    //valid, use in query
}
else
{
    //not numeric, inform the user
}
```

Comment: Nice thx thats helping, yes i know its not protected vs SQL injection, i'm learning that next year on school this is just a test.

Comment: I've updated my answer with more code and explanation to help you further! :)

Comment: I'd personally just use [`int.TryParse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) for the validation. No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: You're right, that one didn't pop in my mind at the time of writing. I'll add it, thanks for reminding me! :)